# load scene loses settings

Tags: python, maya

So i have this very simple code, which should load a scene. It must be part of something  else, but currently it works wrong. I have the scene saved with a lot of changed settings. When I load it from UI, everything is there as it should. But when I load with this code, or by source script.py, then settings are not the same. It's like they are reset to default or not loaded.

I've read the docs about file, and tried few other things, but nothing works. Maya is 2016 ext 1 sp5. I tried with maya 2017 and no such issue there, but other bugs related to animation prevent me from using 2017.

Is there some sort of extra parameter to read settings or something else that I'm missing?

```python
import maya.cmds as cmds

file_path = somefile.ma'
cmds.file( new = True, force = True )
cmds.file(file_path, o=True,type='mayaAscii', options='v=0;p=17;f=0', ignoreVersion=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed, by installing SP6

Answer (score 0):

here's some docs on the file command... it's for maya 2015, but it shouldn't be extremely different in 2016

https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/file.html

looks like you might have to do a combination of the `buildLoadSettings (bls)` flag and the `loadSettings (ls)` flag

I haven't tried it myself, but if I'm reading it correctly it looks like you could use the file command with the buildLoadSettings flag to generate the 'implicitLoadSettings' from it, then run the file command with loadSettings flag specifying 'implicitLoadSettings' so it would look something like this:

```
cmds.file(new=True, force=True)
cmds.file(file_path, open=True, buildLoadSettings=True)
cmds.file(file_path, open=True, loadSettings='implicitLoadSettings')
```

I left out a lot of the other flags - just illustrating the important ones for this example...

Comment: using them together brings this 
# Error: line 1: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 1: Unsaved changes. #
That's the same reason i put cmds.file(new=True, force=True) there.
Using the open flag causes new open, which tries to close the last open file.

Answer (score 0):

What settings are not exactly the same when you load your script?

I'm running Maya 2016 Extension2 SP1. Here's a Mac version:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

file_path = '/Users/swift/Desktop/somefile.ma'

mc.file(new=True, force=True, bls=True)

mc.file(file_path, 
        o = True, 
        type = 'mayaAscii', 
        op = 'v = 0; precision = 20; f = 0', 
        ignoreVersion = True)
```

This code works fine. I checked it. My settings are the same (using UI or using this code).

There's also an error in your code. You missed `'` a single quotation mark in `file_path` line.

Comment: Yeah I missed it while posting here, otherwise it's there. Settings are reset from general settings tab, vray tab, GI tab.

Comment: Also common tab. But not all. For example, animation is reset, but resolution is correct. On render elements tab, settings are also correct.

Comment: It sounds strange, but I have no such effect. All animation and rendering parameters are correct whether I open somefile.ma via Python or via UI. You should reinstall Maya. Or maybe there's some damage in your Python library. Are you using Student Version?

Comment: No it's regular. Anyway got it fixed by installing sp6

Comment: Don't you find my answer useful not accepting it? ))

Comment: Of course it is useful and helpful, but it's not the solution to accept it.